# How to get footer side by side

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer is one below the other and want it to be side by side. My problem is that it is too much do you have any suggestions how to put in a nice way? it's not the most important side of the site but it is much content and how to put this in a right way?

```
                            <h1>Sitemap</h1>

                                <ul>
                                    <li>Opleiding</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Visie & Beleid</li>
                                            <li>Opbouw Studieprogramma</li>
                                            <li>Competenties</li>
                                            <li>Diploma</li>
                                            <li>Beroepen</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Onderwijsprogramma</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Mededelingen</li>
                                            <li>Uitagenda</li>
                                            <li>Propedeuse</li>
                                            <li>Verdieping 1</li>
                                            <li>Verdieping 2</li>
                                            <li>Afstuderen</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Organisatie</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Contact</li>
                                            <li>Blog</li>
                                            <li>Docenten</li>
                                            <li>Onderwijsbureau</li>
                                            <li>Stagebureau</li>
                                            <li>Buitenlandbureau</li>
                                            <li>Examencommissie</li>
                                            <li>Decaan</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Stages en Projecten</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Stages</li>
                                            <li>Projecten</li>
                                        </ul>
                                </ul>

                            <h1>Contact</h1>
                            CMD Amsterdam
                            Bezoekadres: Gebouw Theo Thijssenhuis (TTH), Wibautstraat 2-4, 1091 GM Amsterdam
                            Postadres: Postbus 1025, 1000 BA Amsterdam
                            Telefoon: 020 595 1855
                            Email: <a href="#">info@cmd.hva.nl</a>
                            RSS: <a href="#">Feed intranet</a>

                            <h1>Zoeken</h1>
                            <form>
                                <input type="text">
                                <input type="submit">
                            </form>

                            <h1>About</h1>
                            CMD Amsterdam is een ontwerp opleiding voor Interactieve Media.
                            Op de opleiding Communication & Multimedia Design (CMD) Amsterdam leer je alles over het ontwerpen van online interactieve media. Dit betekent begrijpen, bedenken en maken van interactieve mediatoepassingen zoals websites, mobiele applicaties en interactieve televisie. 

                            <h1>Credits</h1>
                            © 2007 Hogeschool van Amsterdam - DMCI - CMD Amsterdam
                            <a href="#">Geef ons feedback</a>
                        </footer>
```

CSS!

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 317%;
    left: -10%;
    background: lightgrey;
    margin:10%;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: You need to look into the `float` CSS property -- and your footer seems to be missing an opening tag?

Comment: You want the `li`s to be in a row left to right?

Comment: yes i want it from left to right

Comment: O yes thanks i see! forgot it!

Answer (score 1):

```
footer > ul > li {
    width: 20%; /* Make them the right width */
    float: left; /* And float them to get them in a line */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this dont get them side by side only the first LI in the UL

Comment: @Niek Oh, it should be 20% (edited), and you should make sure there isn't anything interfering (padding or other elements).

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 headings in your footer, so I'm guessing you want 5 columns in your footer. I'd put a `div` around each of your footer sections, and then float them and constrain their widths so they appear side-by-side.

#### HTML

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <h1>Sitemap</h1>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <h1>Zoeken</h1>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <h1>About</h1>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <h1>Credits</h1>
    ...
  </div>
</footer>
```

#### CSS

```
.footer-column {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

#### Demo

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TD47/) (**Note**: This will look terrible on a narrow display).